# AWS Cape Town Region has no Git Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

I have recently enabled the Cape Town region on AWS. When I go to Code Deploy Settings in the revision section "My Application is stored on GitHub" option is disabled. I was wondering if there any way to enable the option? Or the option is not available yet in the region?

Comment: Did you try with AWS CLI?

Comment: I have not tried with CLI, I will give it a try.  We are planning to hand it over to a nontechnical person. I am not sure if  CLI solution will work in the long run

Comment: This is just to check if this is AWS console issue, or just there is no github in CT region at all.

Comment: I have got a reply from AWS support, GitHub repo option is not supported at all in the region. Thank you for your Suggestions.

Comment: So its clear now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CodeDeploy does not support Git repo in Cape Town Africa region as Of 15 Jun 2021